# python how to port from xlsxwriter to xlwt

Tags: python, xlwt, xlsxwriter

I want to recreate an xlsxwriter program in xlwt.
I have issues writing a row. Can someone help me with the xlwt module? I found alot of code with xlwt using enumerate, but I am not too familiar with xlwt. The problem I have is, xlwt is writing the whole list as a string in the first cell, so I end up with one column full of data. The xlsxwriter writes each item in the list in its separate cell, which is what I want to do with xlwt. If someone can guide me in right direction, it will be greatly appreciated. thanks

this is my code:

```
def xlsxwriter_res(result):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xlsx')

    for key,value in result.items():
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(key)
        row, col = 0, 0

        for line in value:
            worksheet.write_row(row, col, line) ### Writes each item in list in separate cell
            row += 1

    workbook.close()


def xlwt_res(result):
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")

    for key,value in result.items():
        worksheet = workbook.add_sheet(key)
        row, col = 0, 0

        for line in value:
            worksheet.write(row, col, line) ### Writes the whole list as string in one cell
            row += 1

    workbook.save('filename.xls')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that:

```
import xlwt


def xlwt_res(result):
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")

    for key, value in result.items():
        worksheet = workbook.add_sheet(key)
        row = 0  # we assign 'col' later instead

        for line in value:
            # we're going to iterate over the line object
            # and write directly to a cell, incrementing the column id
            for col, cell in enumerate(line):
                worksheet.write(row, col, cell)  # writes the list contents just like xlsxwriter.write_row!
            row += 1

    workbook.save('filename.xls')


xlwt_res({'one': ["just one element"], 'two': ["that's a list", "did you know it"], 'three': ["let's", "have", "3"]})
```

So both `xlwt` and `xlsxwriter` yield the same results:
[image]

Comment: I can see enumerate now. Thank you very much, this worked as intended.